# Visualizing a break-even analysis with Flex's AreaChart

Tags: apache-flex

How do I visualize a break-even analysis with Flex's AreaChart?

Mats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here is a simple example, based on Adobe LiveDocs :

Be careful, though, there is a bug in Flex AreaSeries that causes tooltip on such series to unproperly render. The AreaSeries displays the yField value of an item for its high value (which is correct), but it displays the same value for the low value (lines 2058 and 2083 of AreaSeries.as)...

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    [Bindable]
    private var expensesAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
        { Month: "Jan", Profit: 2000, Expenses: 1500, Amount: 450 },
        { Month: "Feb", Profit: 1000, Expenses: 200, Amount: 600 },
        { Month: "Mar", Profit: 1500, Expenses: 500, Amount: 300 },
        { Month: "Apr", Profit: 1800, Expenses: 1200, Amount: 900 },
        { Month: "May", Profit: 2400, Expenses: 575, Amount: 500 } ]);
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:SolidColor id="sc3" color="green" alpha=".3"/>
</fx:Declarations>

    <mx:AreaChart id="Areachart" height="100%" width="100%"
         paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5" 
         showDataTips="true" dataProvider="{expensesAC}">

        <mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="Month"/>
        </mx:horizontalAxis>

        <mx:series>
            <mx:AreaSeries
                yField="Profit"
                minField="Expenses"
                areaFill="{sc3}"/>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:AreaChart>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this was exactly what I needed. Sorry I didn't reply until now. You can see what I ended up with [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923954/finished-break-even-areachart-but-can-investors-understand-it).